# Object not looking at / moving towards player after changing the position of the player - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector

I have an object moving towards the player and a trigger that when the player or object hit it they teleport to another area in the map. The object moves towards the player without any issues until the object moves through the teleporter. When the object gains a new position post trigger it just runs off screen. Anyone got any ideas why this might be?

Object chasing player:

```c#
private void Update()
{
    Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(target.transform.position.x,
        target.transform.position.y,
        target.transform.position.z);

    transform.LookAt(targetPosition);

    Monster.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(Monster.transform.position, 
        Player.transform.position, moveSpeed);
}
```

Teleport script:

```c#
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    if (collider.name == Player.name)
    {
        Player.transform.position = new Vector3(XLocation, YLocation, ZLocation);
    }
    if (collider.name == Monster1.name)
    {
        Monster1.transform.position = new Vector3(XLocation, YLocation, ZLocation);
    }
}
```

Comment: where does this object get the player position post trigger?

Comment: The first script is an update method so it's called every frame. So nothing should change post trigger.

Comment: just out of curiosity, but why are you creating a new `Vector3` instead of doing `transform.LookAt(target.transform.position);` directly?

Comment: I did have it as transform.LookAt(target.transform.position); originally but chnaged it just to try something different and to also see the X,Y,Z coords in debug mode which were as expected... The players location.

Comment: after entering the collision, what is the difference between the current player position and the target position of the monster?

Comment: @Alex you could still see the X,Y,Z values if simply using `transform.LookAt(target.transform.position);`. I would always reduce example code to the least code as possible to avoid this kind of questions and draw more focus on the actual problem ;)

Comment: And for your `OnTriggerEnter`: Why not simply doing something like `if(collider.tag == <someTag>) { collider.transform.position = new Vector3(X,Y,Z); }`? Did you debug those names in the `OnTriggerEnter` and see if everything works a s expected there?